# add values from other table using cursor in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to execute the following steps:

Let's say we have a table t1

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (i1 varchar2,d1 varchar2,l1 varchar2, h1 number(1),q1 number, s1 date );

insert into t1 values('123','1','123-1',0,0,sysdate);
insert into t1 values('123','1','234-1',0,0,sysdate+2);
insert into t1 values('456','2','345-1',0,0,sysdate);
insert into t1 values('456','2','456-1',0,0,sysdate+2);

CREATE TABLE t2 (i2 varchar2,d2 varchar2,q2 number,a2 date );

insert into t2 values('123','1','1230',sysdate);
insert into t2 values('123','1','2340',sysdate+1);
insert into t2 values('456','2','3450',sysdate);
insert into t2 values('456','2','4560',sysdate+1);
```

Now I have to order t1 data in ascending order of s1 for same i1 and d1 and then check with a2 column of t2. If a2>=s1 but a2< next greater value of s1 then add q2 and assign it to q1.

I am trying to write a cursor which will take values from t1 in ascending order of s1,

```
for t2.a2>=s1 and t2.a2<s2 --s2 is next greater date value of t1.s1 column
q1 = q1+q2;
```

I am unable to find an efficient way to do this.
my cursor is:

```
cursor c1 is (select * from(select i1,d1,s1,min(s1) from t1 where h1=0 
                   group by i1,d1,s1 order by i1,d1,s1));

declare
  v_s
  v_i
  v_d
  v_s1
  v1   date;
  v_q number;
begin
  open c1;
  fetch c1 into v_i,v_d,v_s,v1;
  loop
    select s1 into v_s1 
    from t1 t 
    where t.i1 = v_i and t.d1=v_d and t.s1>v_s;

    select sum(t2.q2) into v_q 
    from t2 t 
    where t2.i1=v_i and t2.d2=v_d and t2.a2>=v_s and t2.a2<v_s1;

    update t1 set q1 = v_q;
  end loop;
  close c1;
end;
```

I want q1 to be populated with sum(q2) for all a2 dates if a2 falls between min and max(s1).

I am unable to execute this. I either keep getting no data found or too many rows fetched or some other error. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Please post the create table stmt for Table T1 and your expected result.

Comment: Create table t1 (i1 varchar2, d1 varchar2, l1 varchar2, h1 number, q1 number(1), s1 date);     I want q1 to be populated with sum(q2) for all a2 dates if a2 falls between min and max(s1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not shared the end result, I think you want rows 2 & 4 to be null for column Q1. You can try the below co-related sub query to achieve the desired result -

```
UPDATE t1 
   SET Q1 = (SELECT SUM(q2)
               FROM (SELECT t2.*, a2 - lag(a2) over(partition by i2, d2 order by a2) date_diff
                       FROM t2) t2
              WHERE t1.i1 = t2.i2
                AND t1.d1 = t2.d2
                AND t1.s1 <= t2.a2
                AND NVL(date_diff, 1) = 1);
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9f4f0e241571fc500bfae60a06b58d6d)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion@Ankit ! your solution is adding all q2 where s1 <t2.a2 but what i need is sum(q2) when a2 is between two consecutive s1 dates. For example: in the given scenario, 
`insert into t1 values('123','1','125-1',0,0,sysdate+4); 
insert into t2 values('123',1',1230,sysdate+3);`
So the answer I am expecting here is for i1 = 123,d1=1,q1 = 3570 
(as I want sum of t2.q2 when a2 falls between two consecutive s1 dates so 1230+3240 but your solution is adding all values for i1 and giving 4800). Can you please check if its feasible?

Comment: @HeatherDante, Please try the updated query.

Comment: Thanks! your suggestion was quite helpful. Though I did have to tweak around a bit as in your query, you are checking a2 difference as 1 which might not always be the case for my situation and checking for a2 and a2 lag while my requirement is s1-s2 but this gave me an idea how to go on about it.!